# Rails skip over/ignore data for links?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I am setting up previous post links in my Rails app and have the following in my show:

```
<% if @post.previous.blog_key == 'blog' && @post.previous.visible == true %>
 <%= link_to 'previous post', blog_post_path(@post.previous.url_name%>
<% else %>
 <%= link_to 'Home', '/blog/home' %>
<% end %>
```

Then in my model I have:

```
def previous
 SpudPost.where(["published_at < ?", published_at]).last
end

def next
 SpudPost.where(["published_at > ?", published_at]).first
end
```

What I'm trying to do is only have the previous links to go to those blog posts that are marked as having a blog_key that says blog AND marked to be visible. If it's not blog/false then ignore it and go to the next one that says blog and visible.

The problem is that it doesn't go to the next one that says blog/true. If the next one says blog_key == 'news' then it applies to 'Home'. Should it just be another filter within the previous/next methods instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model works better.

```
def previous
 SpudPost.where(blog_key: 'blog').where(visible: true).where(['published_at < ?', published_at]).last
end

def next
 SpudPost.where(blog_key: 'blog').where(visible: true).find_by(['published_at > ?', published_at])
end
```